# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

Tags: php, laravel

Want clone the Message Page in new file name.

**mynewmassagepage.blade.php**

```
@extends('master.main')

@section('main-content')

  @component('master.notification')
    @slot('size')
    col-md-8 col-md-offset-2
    @endslot
    @slot('title')
    Send new message
    @endslot
    @if(session()->has('errormessage'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>Whoops ! </strong><span>{{session()->get('errormessage')}}</span>
    </div>
    @endif
    <form class="" action="{{route('sendmessagepost')}}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient">Recipient:</label>
        <input type="text" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="@if($recipient !== null){{$recipient->username}}@endif" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{old('title')}}" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Text:</label>
        <textarea name="text" class="form-control" style="resize:none" rows="8" cols="80">{{old('text')}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <center>
          <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button>
        </center>
      </div>
      {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>

  @endcomponent

@stop
```

in web.php i use this code:

```
  Route::get('mynewmassagepage}','MessageController@SendView')->name('sendmessage');
  Route::post('mynewmassagepage','MessageController@SendPost')->name('sendmessagepost');
```

I always get the

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

error back. I dont know what i am not make correct,its my first laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Message;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function SendView($username = null){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $recipient = User::where('username',$username)->first();
      return view('message.send')->with([
        'recipient' => $recipient
      ]);
    }

    public function SendPost(Request $request){
      if ($request->recipient == null) {
         session()->flash('errormessage','You must enter recipient\'s username');
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();
      }
      if ($request->text == null) {
         session()->flash('errormessage','You must send something');
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();
      }
      if ($request->title == null) {
         session()->flash('errormessage','You must enter title');
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();
      }
      $recipient = User::where('username',$request->recipient)->first();
      if ($recipient == null) {
        session()->flash('errormessage','User with that username does not exist');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
      }
      if ($recipient->id == Auth::user()->id) {
        session()->flash('errormessage','You cannot send message to yourself');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
      }
      $last_msg = Message::where('from',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
      if ($last_msg !== null) {
        $newTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
        if (Auth::user()->vendor == false) {
          $last_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 minute',strtotime($last_msg->created_at)));
          if ($newTime < $last_time) {
            session()->flash('errormessage','You can send message every minute');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
          }
        } else {
          $last_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+10 seconds',strtotime($last_msg->created_at)));
          if ($newTime < $last_time) {
            session()->flash('errormessage','You can send message every ten seconds');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
          }
        }
      }

      $m = new Message;
      $m->uniqueid = 'ME'.str_random(28);
      $m->to = $recipient->id;
      $m->from = Auth::user()->id;
      $m->title = $request->title;
      $m->text = $request->text;
      $m->save();
      return redirect()->route('messages');
    }

    public function ViewReceived(){
      $received = Message::where('to',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(25);
      return view('message.received')->with([
        'received'=>$received
      ]);
    }

    public function ViewSent(){
      $sent = Message::where('from',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(25);
      return view('message.sent')->with([
        'sent'=>$sent
      ]);
    }
    public function ViewMessage($uniqueid){
      $message = Message::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->first();
      if ($message == null) {
        return redirect()->route('messages');
      }
      if (Auth::user()->id !== $message->to && Auth::user()->id !== $message->from) {
          return redirect()->route('messages');
      }
      if ($message->viewed == false && Auth::user()->id == $message->to) {
         $message->viewed = true;
         $message->save();
      }
      return view('message.view')->with([
         'message'=>$message
      ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception means you're probably sending the wrong type of request to the endpoint e.g. GET to a POST. Or Laravel is missing the route since names are similar.

Try to follow the example below.

```
Route::post('sendmessage/post',[
'use'=>'MessageController@SendPost',
'as'=>'sendmessage.post'
]};


 <form class="" action="{{route('sendmessage.post')}}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient">Recipient:</label>
        <input type="text" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="@if($recipient !== null){{$recipient->username}}@endif" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{old('title')}}" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Text:</label>
        <textarea name="text" class="form-control" style="resize:none" rows="8" cols="80">{{old('text')}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <center>
          <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button>
        </center>
      </div>
      {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typographical error in your code with an extraneous `}`. Remove it, like so.

```
 Route::get('mynewmassagepage','MessageController@SendView')->name('sendmessage');
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?  *Why* does this fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error just because of the invalid route. There is some small mistake in your `Route.php` file, line number 233. Why you are using `}` symbol in `get` route? Remove this extra symbol and use it like,

```
Route::get('/mynewmassagepage','MessageController@SendView')->name('sendmessage');
```